# How to config different authentication filter by url pattern?

Tags: spring-security

I have a spring boot application that provides mainly REST endpoints, auth with JWT. I want use JWT with secret1 to authenticate /internal_api/** API, and JWT with secret2 for others. I don't knows how to configuration for this scenes. Does need two SecurityConfig Class to configure?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .antMatchers("/internal_api/**")
                .addFilterAt(JwtTokenAuthFilter("secret1"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
    }
}
```

I expect user with JWT(secret1) can access /internal_api/** (through JwtTokenAuthFilter("secret1"))
and use with JWT(secret2) can access /other_resource/** (through JwtTokenAuthFilter("secret2")

Comment: What do you mean `JWT with secret` ?Can I assume JWT and secret mean the same thing in your mind ?

Comment: @KenChan you can think one type of token, and other type of token. /internal_api/** use A type token, and other use B type token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through these days online search, I finally found a better implementation.

According to spring [official document](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture) recommended method.

*Creating and Customizing Filter Chains* Section:

> Many applications have completely different access rules for one set of resources compared to another. For example an application that hosts a UI and a backing API might support cookie-based authentication with a redirect to a login page for the UI parts, and token-based authentication with a 401 response to unauthenticated requests for the API parts. Each set of resources has its own WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a unique order and a its own request matcher. If the matching rules overlap the earliest ordered filter chain will win.

```
class  SecurityConfig {
  @Configuration
  @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10)
  class InternalApiConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.antMatcher("/internal_api/**")
        http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/internal_api/**").authenticated()
        http.addFilterAt(JwtTokenAuthFilter("secret1"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }
  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 9)
  class ApiConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/other_resource/**").authenticated()

        http.addFilterAt(JwtTokenAuthFilter("secret2"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the same `JwtTokenAuthFilter`. The point is that you have to decide which roles or authority should an user has in order to access these endpoints. Then during authenticating JWT in `JwtTokenAuthFilter` , you determine if the current requested user have these roles. If yes , make sure the user object that set into `SecurityContext` are assigned with these roles.

Suppose `/internal_api/**` requires `ROLE_INTERNAL` to access while `/other_resource/**` requires `ROLE_OTHER` to access . The configuration looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/internal_api/**").hasRole("INTERNAL")
        .antMatchers("/other_resource/**").hasRole("OTHER")
         //blablbabla.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Sorry, I didn't make it clear. In fact, /internal_api/** is used for other microservices, /other_resource/** is for normal users, they are all authenticated using JWT, but use different secret (HMAC algorithm). So other microservices access internal_api, I need to use secret1 to verify that token is valid. Is there any good solution for this usage scenario?

Comment: Inside `JwtTokenAuthFilter ` , you can use the `HttpServletRequest` to get the request URL . If the request URL is `internal_api` , use secret1 to verify . If it is `other_resource` , use secret2 to verify . Then assign the correct roles based on the request URL . Are there any difficulties ??